# How to get title of onclick button inside javascript function once it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got few onclick buttons inside li . I wonder how I can get the title of each button inside JavaScript function once it is clicked ?I want to set the title of button equal to a variable.Thanks in advance.

```
<javascript>
    function MyFunction(MyFile,MyImage){

    //here i want to get the title of onclick button which is Mango and set it equal to variable.

    }
    </javascript>

    <li><a id="123456" onclick="setCurrentID('123456');javascript:MyFunction('type=fruit&day=friday','http://somesite.com/Image1.png');">Mango</a><img src="http://www.somesite.com/123456.png"></li>
    <li><a id="123457" onclick="setCurrentID('123457');javascript:MyFunction('type=fruit&day=friday','http://somesite.com/Image2.png');">Apple</a><img src="http://www.somesite.com/123457.png"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I mean Mango and Apple in above sample onclick buttons,

Comment: How to get Mango and Apple text via jquery or JavaScript once each one get clicked ?

Comment: I updated my answer below, I was rushing and gave you the wrong attribute.  The function is fixed now.

Comment: Use addEventListeners to handle click and in the listener function this refers to the element which it is clicked. then you can get the title or other attributes of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send the id with the onclick function and then you reference the label via:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").text;
```

So basically:

```
<a id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B1</a><br />
<a id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B2</a><br />
<a id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">B3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var newText = 'Thank You';
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(document.getElementById(clicked_id).text);
    document.getElementById(clicked_id).text = newText;
}
</script>
```

Edit:  Apologies, didn't see you were using anchors instead of buttons as your question mentions, my fault.  I also added how to change the text.

Comment: Thanks for the example.But I want to B1,B2 and B3 not the ids ! Furthermore , Is it possible that i don't  change the structure of on click buttons a lot because the rest of my project depends on same structure !

Comment: Updated with the right code, I meant, firstChild.data not value.

Comment: What do you mean by structure of onclick buttons?

Comment: I mean i dont want to change <a id="123457" onclick= to <button id="123457" onClick

Comment: Sorry, totally misread your code based on your question.  Updated and working.

Comment: Thanks alot  I had to add this.id  to onclick myFunction and it works as i wanted.onclick="setCurrentID('123456');javascript:myFunction('type=fruit&day=friday','http://somesite.com/Image1.png',this.id);

Answer (score 1):

> Do not use `inline-event-binding`.

Use `innerHTML`, it will return HTML/Text content (inner) of an element.

`$(SELECTOR).next()` will grab the next element..`.attr()` will return specified attribute of the element.

Try this:

```js
var CurrentID;
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setCurrentID(this.id);
  MyFunction('type=fruit&day=friday', $(this).next('img').attr('src'), this.innerHTML);
});

function setCurrentID(id) {
  CurrentID = id;
}

function MyFunction(MyFile, MyImage, MyTitle) {
  alert('MyFile: ' + MyFile + '  MyImage: ' + MyImage + ' MyTitle:' + MyTitle)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="123456">Mango</a>
    <img src="http://www.somesite.com/123456.png">
  </li>
  <li><a id="123457">Apple</a>
    <img src="http://www.somesite.com/123457.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/5o752ypy/)

Comment: Why not just use the text property of the anchor tag?  I feel like I am missing something with how complex your response is from the question.

Comment: `Node.textContent` could be used but it will fail `IE < 9`

Comment: Ah, sometimes forget about backwards compat for IE.  Makes sense.  Thank you!